# "Semicolon or block is expected" error when using tailwind responsive classes in svelte-kit style tags

Tags: svelte, tailwind-css, sveltekit

When using tailwind responsive classes (ex: `md:my-auto`, `focus:ring-0`, `focus:outline-none`) in svelte kit component style tags, I get the following error:

```
500

Semicolon or block is expected

ParseError: Semicolon or block is expected
    at error (/var/www/html/node_modules/svelte/compiler.js:16752:20)
    at Parser$1.error (/var/www/html/node_modules/svelte/compiler.js:16828:10)
    at Object.read_style [as read] (/var/www/html/node_modules/svelte/compiler.js:13141:21)
    at tag (/var/www/html/node_modules/svelte/compiler.js:15887:34)
    at new Parser$1 (/var/www/html/node_modules/svelte/compiler.js:16787:22)
    at parse$3 (/var/www/html/node_modules/svelte/compiler.js:16919:21)
    at compile (/var/www/html/node_modules/svelte/compiler.js:30012:18)
    at compileSvelte (/var/www/html/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/dist/index.js:244:48)
    at async TransformContext.transform (/var/www/html/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/dist/index.js:837:27)
    at async Object.transform (/var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b5f3ba8.js:44285:30)
```

Here is the code for my component:

```html
<script>
    export let switched = false;
</script>
<button class="switch-button transition-transform transform ease-in-out duration-300" class:-rotate-180={switched}
        on:click={()=>{switched = !switched}}>
    <span class="text-2xl md:hidden"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></span>
    <span class="text-xl hidden md:inline"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span>
</button>
<style lang="postcss" type="text/postcss">
    .switch-button {
        @apply border-none appearance-none md:my-auto my-2 font-bold text-center rounded-full h-12 w-12 bg-red-500 text-white;
    }
    .switch-button:focus{
        @apply outline-none;
    }
    .switch-button:active{
        @apply bg-red-300;
    }
</style>
```

I'm unsure what's causing this issue in particular. I have a feeling it might just be a svelte-kit bug. I know there are work arounds like using vanilla css for responsiveness instead of tailwind classes, or using an external css files, but I would rather not use those options as I very much like the tailwind classes.

Please let me know if you know what's happening here, or if you need more information regarding my projects environment, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Link to my projects source code: https://github.com/DriedSponge/GorillianCurrencyConversion

Version information:

- svelte-kit: `1.0.0-next.109`
- tailwindcss: `2.1.2`
- vite: `2.3.4`

(I do have jit enabled on tailwind)

Comment: I have the same issue but only when running tests with jest.
Have you managed to make it work with the tests ?
here is my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827337/error-with-tailwind-complex-class-focus-etc-and-jest-in-svelte-project-only

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you need to add a Svelte preprocessor to handle your PostCSS syntax (which Tailwind uses since it's a PostCSS plugin). Since you already have [`svelte-preprocess`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess) installed in your `package.json`, you only need to add [`postcss-load-config`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-load-config) to allow `svelte-preprocess` to find your `postcss.config.js`.

Install `postcss-load-config` with:

```
npm install --save-dev postcss-load-config
```

Next, you'll want to configure your `svelte.config.js` file to use `svelte-preprocess`. In your case, you'll want your `svelte.config.js` file to look like this:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static'
// import the preprocessor
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  // added these lines:
  preprocess: [
    preprocess({
      postcss: true,
    }),
  ],

  kit: {
    // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
    target: '#svelte',
    adapter: adapter({
      // default options are shown
      pages: 'build',
      assets: 'build',
      fallback: null,
    }),
  },
}

export default config
```

I believe that this *should* work, but when I tried it out, your styles seemed to break. To remedy this, I moved the `@tailwind` directives out of your `__layout.svelte` and into an `app.postcss` file (next to your `app.html`, inside `/src/src`). Use this stylesheet in your `__layout.svelte` by importing it with:

```html
<script>
    import '../app.postcss'
</script>
<main>
<-- rest of your layout -->
</main>
<style lang="postcss">
    @import url('...');
    :global(body)  {
        background-color: #0E1013;
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

For your next project, maybe consider using [`svelte-add` to install Tailwind](https://github.com/svelte-add/tailwindcss), which (should) take care of everything for you. These fixes were based on the files it adds for you.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error. Had everything set up exactly like @person_v1.32 described, the build was working fine, but `VSCode` gave me the error.
Turned out for me it was caused by using a `monorepo` where svelte was used in a module/package only.

Fix ? Specifying the `postcss/tailwind configs` with `absolute path`.

- `svelte.config.js`:

```js
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const postcssConfig = path.join(__dirname, 'postcss.config.cjs');

export default {
  preprocess: [
    vitePreprocess(),
    sveltePreprocess({
      postcss: {
        configFilePath: postcssConfig
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

- `postcss.config.cjs`

```js
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const path = require('path');
const tailwindConfig = path.join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.cjs');

const config = {
  plugins: [
    //Some plugins, like tailwindcss/nesting, need to run before Tailwind,
    tailwindcss({ config: tailwindConfig }),
    //But others, like autoprefixer, need to run after,
    autoprefixer
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `"files.associations": {"*.svelte": "html" }` inside your VSCode settings

Comment: This is not recommended anymore. See https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode : If you added "files.associations": {"*.svelte": "html" } to your VSCode settings, remove it.