# Svelte + Tailwind: "Semicolon or block is expected"

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, postcss

I have a Svelte project using Tailwind, with this style in a component:

```
<style global lang="postcss">
  input {
    @apply block border-black border-2 mb-4 p-2 outline-none focus:border-blue-500;
  }
</style>
```

The error that I'm getting, caused by the `focus:` class:

```
Semicolon or block is expected
```

My postcss.config.cjs file:

```
import tailwind from 'tailwindcss'
import tailwindConfig from './tailwind.config.cjs'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'

export default {
  plugins: [tailwind(tailwindConfig), autoprefixer]
}
```

tailwind.config.cjs:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  content: ["./index.html", './src/**/*.{svelte,js,ts}'], // for unused CSS
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  darkMode: 'media', // or 'media' or 'class'
}
```

vite.config.js:

```
import postcss from './postcss.config.cjs'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  css: {
    postcss
  }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Semicolon or block is expected" error when using tailwind responsive classes in svelte-kit style tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758422/semicolon-or-block-is-expected-error-when-using-tailwind-responsive-classes-in)

Comment: I saw that answer, the config files are specific to svelte-kit

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
"files.associations": {"*.svelte": "html" }
```

I'm using sveltekit+postcss+tailwind with Cursor as IDE (I'm sure it also work in vscode). All `<style>` use `lang="postcss"`.